# NPM installing package with multiple folders for package

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently started a new node project and ran `npm install *name* --save` for both express and nodemon and noticed that 20-30 folders appear in my node_modules folder related to the two packages instead of just express and nodemon. This has never happened when I have run this command with previous projects. Is there any reason why this is happening now?

I expected my node_modules folder to only have "express" and "nodemon"

npm version: 3.3.6
node version: 5.0.0

[image: Example of what I mean]

Comment: how to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stumbled upon your post with a Google Search and thought I'd link the answer :

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is
>   possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR
>   dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder
>   with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another
>   when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

See npm@3's [release notes](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#flat-flat-flat).